# Find and replace multiple strings in a text file with powershell and regex

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

Hello all and thank you in advance for your help,

I have a list of same links in a txt file and need to replace one string '**username**' in multiple lines in it : example of one line in a file (string to replace in bold)

[https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**username**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D](https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**username**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D)

List of users from file : example C:\Temp\names.txt . File structure like : john bob merry and so on...

output to the txt file should be like :

[https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**bob**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D](https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**bob**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D) [https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**john**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D](https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**john**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D) [https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**merry**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D](https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**merry**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D)

all the replacements should be taken from a txt file

This code isn't working, it is just an example :

```
$RUSER=Select-String -Pattern "username" -AllMatches | % {  $_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups[1].value} $RUSER > $output_file
```

Comment: Does `names.txt` contain a single line with multiple usernames separated by whitespace, or does it contain multiple lines (ie. one user name per line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = 'username' <#write your pattern there#>
$url = "https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/**username**@svgauth%3Fsecret%3D"
$names =[string[]](get-content $home\Names.txt).Split(' ')
$names | % {[regex]::Replace($url,$pattern,$_)} | Out-File $home\resultNames.txt
```

Comment: I guess the `username` is variable, like `FletcherF1@svgauth...` It's surely not `username` literally.

Comment: author : "List of users from file : example C:\Temp\names.txt . File structure like : john bob merry and so on..." my answer will works fine

Comment: @Jan i correct my answer with adding $pattern variable.